# Doing calculations on properties

Tags: maven, maven-2

Is it possible to do string and math operations on properties in maven 2?

I have a property `${version}` that has a value of something like **5.3.0-SNAPSHOT**, now I'd like to extract the 5 and do some math on it, say subtract 3 from it. So my new property would get the value 2.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at the [parse-version](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) goal of [build helper maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/). As the example in [this page](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin//usage.html) indicates, once this goal is run, it makes available a bunch of propeties which can be used to do subsequent operations.

```
parsedVersion.majorVersion
parsedVersion.minorVersion
parsedVersion.incrementalVersion
parsedVersion.qualifier
parsedVersion.buildNumber
```

Comment: That saves me the work if substring, now I only need to do math on the values.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example here (http://ronalleva.com/groovy/maven/programming/2008/01/23/using-the-groovy-maven-plugin-to-do-magic.html) which embeds groovy into your plugin.  Further in the example he sets a property in the maven project.